# How do you replace colors in a ggmap object?

Tags: r, raster, ggmap

I'm using a Stamen background map in the `ggmap` package. I would like to replace all of the black elements in raster background image (i.e. colors `"#000000"` with say `"#C0C0C0"` - to basically look more like the [toner light](http://maps.stamen.com/toner-lite/#12/37.7706/-122.3782) background map).

```
library(ggmap)
loc <- c(left = -73.706, bottom = 42.6940, right = -73.648, top = 42.7921)
troy <- get_map(location = loc, zoom = 13, maptype = "toner", source = "stamen")
ggmap(troy)
```

Replacing the colors as per below only returns the raster part, and strips the object of its ggmap class.

```
class(troy)
troy[troy == "#000000"] <- "#C0C0C0"
ggmap(troy)
class(troy)
```

Is there a way to replace the raster cells while not altering the other attributes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can manually change `class` and `attr` to match the original raster.

```
library(ggmap)
loc <- c(left = -73.706, bottom = 42.6940, right = -73.648, top = 42.7921)
troy <- get_map(location = loc, zoom = 13, maptype = "toner", source = "stamen")

attr_troy <- attr(troy, "bb")    # save attributes from original

# change color in raster
troy[troy == "#000000"] <- "#C0C0C0"

# correct class, attributes
class(troy) <- c("ggmap", "raster")
attr(troy, "bb") <- attr_troy
ggmap(troy)
```